Getting Cognos reports duration from ContentStore db
im trying to query the content store db to get the duration of reports that were executed at some point .
what im trying to achieve is have a query that returns reports that run for more than X amount of minutes . i dont have audit enabled and i want to do it without audit enabled . 
 
i found the reports in the CMOBJECTS table , got their names , but i cant find the table that hold the information of startDate and endDate , any help would be much appreciated .

This kind of information is captured in the Cognos Analytics Audit database if configured.  You can use the sample audit package to calculate the report runtimes.  Please see the following link for more details:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/calculate-start-time-reports-audit-package

we dont have audit configured and im looking for a way to find the information in contentStore , since it is available in the admin console of cognos i suppose i should be able to find it in the content Store no ?

The content store is a transactional.  I would not recommend reporting against it directly.  Additionally the ERD is not public, nor is guaranteed to be the same version over version.  Setting up auditing would be the way to go from my point of view.

The Content Store database contains data about objects and their relationships to each other.  Usage data is, by definition, part of a system audit feature.  You can look in the Content Store all you like, but you won't find audit data.  That would be in the Audit database.
If the Audit database is not configured, maybe you can get what you need using the cogaudit.log file.
Looking at a single report request using DQM, I see these in the same session for the same report:
Query Service returned response for "execute" request
.
.
Query Service returned response for "releaseDataset" request

It seems it would be painful to try to develop a solution to reliably parse the text file, but it may be possible.
Keep in mind that you may run into trouble with your logging settings.  Files are ended and created on a schedule or when they reach a certain size.  Old files may or may not be kept.  The number kept is also configurable.  You may need to include in your process a step to copy the logs to a different location where Cognos won't automatically destroy them.

Honestly, if you have access to the Content Store database, you must be a Cognos admin and have access to the Cognos install.  I recommend configuring an Audit database.  It's far easier and more reliable than what this answer suggests.
